# how to get content news like Safari's “Reader Mode”

Tags: php

Safari has a **"Reader Mode"** which removes everything from a website with an article but the text.

Now I need to get HTML source from site and then get real content news like Safari's “Reader Mode” with **PHP**!
can you help me?? :S

Comment: It's based on an algorithm that tries to identify the main content portion of a web site. There's no defined standard for that, you'll have to try and implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Someone pointed out that simply posting a link to another post is not very helpful so I'm updating. I have since started using a PHP port of Arc90's Readability and it works really well.

Here is a link to the PHP port of Readability.js: http://www.keyvan.net/2010/08/php-readability/

Here is an simple example of implementation:

```
$url = 'http://';
$html = file_get_contents($url);

if (function_exists('tidy_parse_string')) {
    $tidy = tidy_parse_string($html, array(), 'UTF8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();
    $html = $tidy->value;
}

// give it to Readability
$readability = new Readability($html, $url);
// echo $readability->html;
// echo htmlspecialchars($tidy($readability->html, true));

// print debug output?
// useful to compare against Arc90's original JS version -
// simply click the bookmarklet with FireBug's console window open
$readability->debug = false;
// convert links to footnotes?
$readability->convertLinksToFootnotes = false;

$readability->lightClean = false;
// $readability->revertForcedParagraphElements = false;

// process it
$result = $readability->init();
// store reference to dom content processed by Readability
$content = $readability->getContent();

echo '<h1>'.$readability->getTitle()->textContent.'</h1>';
echo $content->innerHTML;
```

### Expanding on the Above

If you want to open up the number of pages this works on I've found you can curl and define user agent for the html before passing to Readability and you'll get better results. Throw in some redirect following and it's even better.

Here is the function I'm using instead of file_get_contents:

```
function getData($url) {
    $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', urldecode(trim($url)) );
    $timeout = 5;
    $cookie = tempnam('/tmp', 'CURLCOOKIE');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $content;
}
```

Implementation:

```
$url = 'http://';
//$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html = getData($url);

if (function_exists('tidy_parse_string')) {
    $tidy = tidy_parse_string($html, array(), 'UTF8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();
    $html = $tidy->value;
}

$readability = new Readability($html, $url);

//...
```

Comment: Please add the important parts of the solution. If the link brakes, your answer is lost.